# Server gradually loses connection to MongoDB until it doesn't connect at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server, nodemon

Good Morning and day to all! I hope this makes sense. I was on here last week as I was missing one step to change my `app.js` file to `server.js` and got enough help to make it work. I am returning with an new issue that perhaps stem from that one.. Here is what's happening:

I am working on a MEAN app and I've been working as usual typing `mongod` to have mongoDB running. and i was using `npm start` because it was advice to me but usually i use `nodemon`

I've noticed that gradually my server just completely disconnects and I have to manually restart it by typing 'npm start' again. The connection last about 1 minute before it loses it. However now it doesn't connect at all. I think it has something to do with losing connection to MongoDB because I have a `console.log` for whenever I don't have mongoDB running to remind me.. (and this is the console log that my server spits out)

**server.js**

```
require('net').connect(27017, 'locahost').on('error', function(){
console.log("He's name is MongoDB live from port 27017");
 process.exit(0);

});
```

I tried switching back to running it with `nodemon` while it gives me the impression that it's connected as it doesn't spit out any errors when I update any part of my code or refresh the page, it just spits out the console.log message that I showed above and I have to exit and restart..with `npm run devel` I have no luck either. (this is not happening in other applications)

Here is a look at my command line with all 3 attempts to connect to the server and notice how it spits out the `console.log` message.. I refresh my page and it doesn't connect at all anymore. It used to! as I mentioned before but for a minute or so. I hope someone can help me out and point me in the right direction.

using `npm start`, `npm run devel` and `nodemon`

[image: my terminal starting server]

Package.JSON file

[image]

Comment: Good Morning. I am still having this issue. Other projects don't have this problem. This one seems to be the only that keeps disconnecting abruptly. Anybody have an idea what could be different with the info I have here? Thanks again!

Comment: Could it be that i UPGRADED to Mongo db 3.0 while in development of this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a friend actually pointed something out to me in my server.js code. I don't recall why but the line that reads `process.exit(0);` is what's causing mongodDB to lose connection with the server. We removed that it and voila! works like a charm. )no idea how that got there.